# Why i can't import torch?

Tags: pytorch

I downloaded and installed CUDA10.0 pyhton3.6 pytorch1.2. , also loaded cuda/cuda-10.0-x86_6 envirnment.

Commands like below

```
module load cuda/cuda-10.0-x86_64

# CUDA 10.0
conda install pytorch==1.2.0 torchvision==0.4.0 cudatoolkit=10.0 -c pytorch
```

Because it needs to be installed on a **NO-NETWOEK** centOs server! Therefore, all pakages need be downloaded in advance and run command like below.

```
conda install --offline pytorch-1.2.0-cuda100py36h938c94c_0.tar.bz2
......
```

---

The error occured below.

```
Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016, 12:22:00) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import torch
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/data/users/CHDHPC/2020224009/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/__init__.py", line 81, in <module>
    from torch._C import *
ImportError: libmkl_gnu_thread.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I have no idea to solve it! Anyone can help me! Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed this issue by changing Python version to 3.6.2 and re-installing the cuda and cudnn.
Pecfect!